# Производительность при работе с CardView

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview, производительность, cardview

Здравствуйте. Есть `RecyclerView`, заполненный `CardView`. Внутри каждого `CardView` находится `ListView` с элементами. При вертикальной прокрутке такой конструкции заметны лаги. В `RecyclerView` и `ListView` использованы `ViewHolder`'ы. Вопрос таков: стоит ли пробовать заменять `ListView` внутри `CardView` тоже на `RecyclerView` или это все равно не поможет? И есть ли какие-то еще способы ускорить их загрузку?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

***UPD:***
Заменил `ListView` на `RecyclerView`, стало немного лучше, но лаги все равно есть.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в конфликте вложенных скролящихся элементов. Лаги не из-за большого объема данных, а из-за "непонимания" какой элемент должен скролится.

Comment: @pavlofff есть какие-нибудь способы улучшить ситуацию?

Answer (score 1):

Дело тут вовсе не в `CardView`, время отклика вашего списка больше, чем 16 мСек.

Можете попробовать вынести в другой поток, либо подгружать данные порциями(если их много), так-же вполне возможно, что телефон попросту не успевает отрисовывать итемы, и проблема слабого железа.

По той информации, что вы сообщили, бОльшего подсказать нельзя.

Comment: Адаптер и так подгружает данные на виджет "порциями", для списков это не проблема, более того, именно поэтому и используется адаптер.